# Data not updating on ie 9/10 in application developed using angularjs

Tags: spring-mvc, angularjs

I am developing a simple user management system using angularjs. It's simple add, update and delete kind of application. I am using spring-mvc in back-end for getting JSON response.
Everything works fine in Firefox, Chrome and Safari but IE..!!!!

I have one page which lists all users. For the first time it will work fine in IE9/10 but any update done on any user will not be reflected in view (using IE).

I am not able to figure out what is happening. I think IE9/10 will also cache json data, and each time when user list page is called it will bind that cached data with page.

Is it possible to make IE9/10 forget those loaded data?

**Angular module for accessing web-service :**

```
angular.module("user.service", ["ngResource"]).
  factory('User', function($resource, $rootScope) {
    var User = $resource(
      $rootScope.apipath + 'users/:userId', {userId: '@id'},
      {update: {method: 'PUT'}}
    );

    User.prototype.isNew = function() {
      return (typeof(this.id) === 'undefined');
    };

    return User;
});
```

**UserList Controler :**

```
function UserListController($scope, User) {
    $scope.users = User.query();
}
```

**UserList Tamplate :**

```
<h2><msg key="users"></msg><a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" href="#/users/new"><i class="icon-plus-sign icon-white"></i><msg key="addnew"></msg></a></h2>

<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th><msg key="username"></msg></th>
        <th><msg key="name"></msg></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="user in users">

        <td>{{user.userId}}</td>
        <td>{{user.contact.firstName}} {{user.contact.lastName}}</td>
        <td>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <a class="btn btn-info" href="#/users/{{user.id}}">
                    <i class="icon-pencil icon-white"></i><msg key="edit"></msg>
                </a> 
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Without the plunker, impossible to tell.

Comment: thanks for quick reply @Stewie my web-service is not up so even plunker will not help, I have updated required piece of code from each file. app.js has routing logic and index.html only contains <ng-view> and menu as header. If you required those files i can put code over here. Thanks.

Comment: You say the problem appears when you update the user data but you fail to show the actual code with which you are doing the update.

Comment: no issue is not with data updation, data get updated in datbase but do not call server for the second time when we try to view userdetail page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After googling I found a solution to this problem.

This situation occurs due to caching of json in IE 9/10. We need to tell ie not to cache json data.
As a solution, I created a java-filter at server which intercepts each request came for web-services or say for json data. And I added following headers in response

1. Cache-Control : no-cache
2. Pragma : no-cache
3. Expires : -1

These headers in response object will tell IE not to cache data received with this response.

Filter is as follows :

```
    public class NoCacheFilter implements Filter {

    /**
     * Place this filter into service.
     *
     * @param filterConfig the filter configuration object used by a servlet
     * container to pass information to a filter during initialization
     * @throws ServletException to inform the container to not place the filter
     * into service
     */
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    /**
     * Set cache header directives.
     *
     * @param servletRequest provides data including parameter name and values,
     * attributes, and an input stream
     * @param servletResponse assists a servlet in sending a response to the
     * client
     * @param filterChain gives a view into the invocation chain of a filtered
     * request
     */
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;

        String requestUrl = httpServletRequest.getRequestURL().toString();

        // set cache headers
        httpServletResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        httpServletResponse.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        httpServletResponse.setDateHeader("Expires", -1);

        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }

    /**
     * Take this filter out of service.
     */
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

We are developing a large AngularJs application and ran into caching issues as well in IE.  The ultimate fix was to add cache control header to the api response messages.

```
Cache-Control: no-store
```

Another option is to create a http interceptor which appends a unique timestamp so each request is different and not cached.

[See this article by Jef Claes about information on how to create the http interceptor](http://www.jefclaes.be/2013/06/angularjs-and-ie8-caching.html).

*code example from the post*

```
var AppInfrastructure = angular.module('App.Infrastructure', []);

AppInfrastructure
    .config(function ($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.requestInterceptors.push('httpRequestInterceptorCacheBuster');
    })    
    .factory('httpRequestInterceptorCacheBuster', function () {
        return function (promise) {
            return promise.then(function (request) {
                if (request.method === 'GET') {
                    var sep = request.url.indexOf('?') === -1 ? '?' : '&';
                    request.url = request.url + sep + 'cacheSlayer=' + new Date().getTime();
                }

                return request;
            });
        };
    });
```

Comment: thanks @Mark, i gone through this link and angular documentation but i found there isn't any request interceptor exist with angular. Agular has Response interceptor but i couldn't find Request Interceptor.