# spring controller is being called only when the developer tools is opened in IE

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc, internet-explorer

I want to reload the data when user click on a button. Issue is with IE. When the button is clicked, the **spring controller is not getting called when tested in IE**, but works fine in chrome. Other thing i noticed is **in IE, it is working properly when i open developer tools**.Below is my code:

html code:

```
 <table style="width:100%;height:80%;" ng-controller="loadingSampleCtrl">
<tr> <td><button type="button" ng-click="loadData()">Reload data</button></td></tr>
   <object-reloadable></object-reloadable>
  </table>
```

js code:

```
app.directive('objectReloadable', function() {
    var link = function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var currentElement = element;

        scope.$watch('pdfName', function(newValue, oldValue) {
            scope.loading = true;
            if (newValue !== oldValue) {
                scope.loading = false;
                scope.pdfName = newValue;
                var html = '<object style="width: 100%; height: 1200px;overflow-y: hidden; cursor:pointer;" type="application/pdf" data="' + scope.pdfName.filePath + '" ></object>';
                if(scope.pdfName.filePath == "undefined"){
                    scope.loading = true;
                } else {
                    scope.pdfName = newValue;
                    scope.html = '<object style="width: 100%; height: 1200px;overflow-y: hidden; cursor:pointer;" type="application/pdf" data="' + scope.pdfName.filePath + '" ></object>';
                }
                var replacementElement = angular.element(scope.html);
                currentElement.replaceWith(replacementElement);
                currentElement = replacementElement;
            }
        });
    };
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: false,
        link: link
    };
})

myApp.controller('loadingSampleCtrl', function ($scope, FilesService) {
    $scope.loadData = function () {
    $scope.loading = true;
    FilesService.fileRead().then(
        function (response) {
            alert("response back from spring controllerf");
            if(window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob){
                $scope.IEBrowser = true;
                $scope.loading = false;
                $scope.pdfName = response;
                /*$timeout(function() {
                    $scope.pdfName = response;
                }, 0);*/
            } else {
                $scope.IEBrowser = false;
                $scope.pdfName = response;
                $scope.loading = false;
            }
        },
        function (errResponse) {
            $rootScope.showError("Internal error" + errResponse);
        }); 
    }
    $scope.loadData();
});

//service call
    _fileService.fileRead = function(){
           var deferred = $q.defer();
        var repUrl = myAppURL+'/myFilesToRead/getFileData.form';
        $http.get(repUrl).then(
                function (response) {
                    deferred.resolve(response.data);
                },
                function(errResponse){
                    console.error('Error while fetching RTC Defects detail data' + errResponse);
                    deferred.reject(errResponse);
                }
            );
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

spring controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/getFileData", method = RequestMethod.GET,produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public
    @ResponseBody
    List<String> getFileData(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("In spring controller, getFiledata"); //This is not being invoked from IE
    //logic here
    //return statement
}
```

With the above code, chrome is working fine but when tested in IE, when user click on Reload data button, it is not calling the spring controller(getFileData(..)) to get the latest data, instead it is returning the same old data, but when i clicked on f12 and opened developer tools it is invoking the spring controller. I'm using IE11 and no errors are shown in the console.

Comment: What do you see on `console` if any?

Comment: console is blank. Nothing is seen,Please see loadingSampleCtrl js code, before i commented $timeout(function() .. it showed timeout is not defined. But now after i commented it no errors are shown and working fine in chrome.

Comment: Cna you debug and see? Check this line `if (newValue !== oldValue)` in your `directive`.

Comment: yes it is entering the if(newValue !== oldValue) condition, i have kept alert statements and seen. Even it is hitting the service call _fileService.fileRead = function(){..) but issue is not hitting the spring controller, the System.out.print statement in spring controller is not printed too (in IE without developer tools).

Comment: @RossiRobinsion - Any suggestions?I think it is happening because of element used in objectReloadable js code.function(scope, element, attrs)

Comment: When calling the backend, where does your response land? In the success or error? Have you seen any request made in the `network` tab?

Comment: Or maybe it's the caching issue. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232169/data-not-updating-on-ie-9-10-in-application-developed-using-angularjs

Comment: response lands in success, no request is made.it is only hitting the service and then returning back to the js controller without hitting the spring controller.

Comment: I dont think its a caching issue, i'm creating objectReloadable element on the fly just to make it work in IE and then it started loading PDF in IE. Please see app.directive('objectReloadable', function()..) in my post above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150041/discussion-between-dim-and-rossi-robinsion).